# Secure way to log PHP exception trace (that might include sensible credentials)

Tags: php, security, logging

**CONTEXT**

I have a web app and I catch my exception globally to log them into a file inside my app (`/app/log/app.log`). A public folder make impossible to browse outside as it is mounted to be served to the client (`/public/index.php`).

I also use a modified version of `Exception::getTraceAsString()`, which let me have the full strings instead of PHP truncating the strings in this trace (the code is really trivial, I will not put the class here because it is not relevant for the question I am asking).

Here is an example of what my `app.log` file looks like:

```
2018-06-10 14:33:12.7016 (+02:00) [ERRO] Error of type PDOException catched
2018-06-10 14:33:12.7020 (+02:00) [DBUG] Error catched on line 22 of file C:\xampp\htdocs\my-app\app\bootstrap\database.php
2018-06-10 14:33:12.7026 (+02:00) [DBUG] #0 [internal function]: PDO->__construct('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;port=3306;adapter=;prefix=', 'root', '', Array)
2018-06-10 14:33:12.7028 (+02:00) [DBUG] #1 [internal function]: Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo->connect(Array)
2018-06-10 14:33:12.7031 (+02:00) [DBUG] #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\my-app\app\bootstrap\database.php(22): Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo->__construct(Array)
2018-06-10 14:33:12.7034 (+02:00) [DBUG] #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\my-app\public\index.php(7): include('C:\xampp\htdocs\my-app\app\bootstrap\database.php')
```

Knowing that i would like to dispose of those information outside my app, let us say SaaS service for storing and searching across various log destinations (which might potentially be visible by employee of the SaaS system).

**PROBLEM**

As you can see, my `app.log` can sometimes contains sensible content like passwords.

**QUESTION**

Is there a state-of-the-art way to handle the sensibility of the content in our log traces?

Also, what about the security regarding the fact that absolute paths are visible in our logs?

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Security_Logging_Project

Comment: @bxN5 I am definitively gonna check this OWASP package, do you know if there is an official OWASP maintainted equivalent of this java project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a state-of-the-art way to handle the sensibility of the content in our log traces?
>
> Also, what about the security regarding the fact that absolute paths are visible in our logs?

The best thing you can do here is to encrypt the logs with a public key, for which the corresponding secret key is only known to your operations team and/or developers.

That is to say, I recommend using a [sealing API](https://paragonie.com/white-paper/2015-secure-php-data-encryption#crypto-seal) to encrypt the log information.

Since you asked about state-of-the-art, I would specifically recommend `sodium_crypto_box_seal()` / `sodium_crypto_box_seal_open()` here. (PHP 7.2+)

Comment: Do you personnaly use this mecanism? Is the decrypting step doable from my browser (using maybe an extension in my browser), as I will also need my non-developer collegues to be able to decrypt those, or do you recommand creating a small web app to specifically address this issue?

Comment: The purpose of a sealing API is that only your developers can decrypt, not arbitrary browsers. That being said, yes, I do use this API in my own projects.